# Necessary and sufficient conditions of a well-ordered set to be of order type $\omega$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

I want to find some necessary and sufficient conditions of a well-ordered set to be of order type $\omega$.

To be specific, let $A$ be a well-ordered set, if each element of $A$ except the smallest one has an immediate predecessor, then is the order type of $A$ "at most $\omega$"? (Selfishly by the words "at most $\omega$" I mean there is an order-preserving injection from $A$ to $\mathbb{Z}_+$.) I feel it is true intuitively, but I don't know how to find the order-preserving injection.

Could you tell me whether the proposition is true and how to prove it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. An uninteresting proof is trivial: If the order type is not at most $\omega$ then it is at least $\omega+1$, which means there is an element, namely $\omega$, which does not have an immediate predecessor.

Maybe slightly more interesting: Show by induction that every element of $A$ has only finitely many predecessors...

Comment: I do not understand the first proof. Maybe it is meant to signify as known the fact that given any two well-orderings, one is an initial segment of the other...

Comment: @david Thanks. Could you explain how to show by induction that every element of $A$ has only finitely many predecessors?

Comment: @Q.Huang Let $X$ be the set of elements of $A$ which have infinitely many elements below them. Since $A$ is well-ordered, $X$ has a least element, $x$. Can $x$ have an immediate predecessor?

Comment: @AndrésCaicedo Well, yes. That seemed to follow from the way the question was stated: If we don't know that then what sense does "order type at most $\omega$" make?

Comment: "[O]rder type at most $\omega$" makes perfect sense even if you do not know that any well-ordering is comparable with the ordering of the natural numbers.

Comment: @AndrésCaicedo Some people would say the word "any" is best avoided in a sentence like that, because it can be read as "some" or as "every". (I assume you meant "every", because then it makes sense, but I honestly read it the other way at first, which was confusing.) I do not believe I've ever head "at most $x$" used for "less than or equal to $x$" in the context of a _partial_ order. When I read "order type at most $\omega$" it convinces me that the writer has a total order in mind. It's a question of Engllish usage.

Comment: @NoahSchweber $x$ cannot have an immediate predecessor, since if so then the immediate predecessor of $x$ also has infinitely many elements below it, which is a contradiction to the fact $x$ is the smallest element of $X$. But this may make another contradiction. $x$ cannot be the smallest element of $A$ since there is infinitely many elements below $x$, and then $x$ should be supposed to have an immediate predecessor. Your reduction to absurdity is good. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I feel apologetic as I have indeed made some confusion in my expression. I tried to express there is an order-preserving injection from $A$ to $\mathbb{Z}_+$, and I selfishly used the words "at most". Now it have been completed in above question. Thank you.